# how can i get url of gateway to make paging in microservices

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, microservices, .net-6.0, gateway

ı am coding a microservice architectural with gateway in .NET6 web api.
My gateway run on 5000 port on local,
a microservice run on 5001 port on local,
other microservice run on 5002 port on local
i want to make a pagging in microservices and i return response with pagging links like next,previous...
When I make a request to microservices on the gateway, the response I get is as follows

```
"links": {
    "_previous": "https://localhost:5001/api/customers/5/5?page=4&size=5",
    "_next": "https://localhost:5001/api/customers/5/5?page=6&size=5",
    "_first": "https://localhost:5001/api/customers/5/5?page=1&size=5",
    "_last": "https://localhost:5001/api/customers/5/5?page=1207&size=5"
},
```

but I want the links to come on the host(localhost:5000) of the gateway like the example below

```
"_previous": "https://localhost:5000/api/customers/5/5?page=4&size=5"
```

I looked at sample questions, I did research on the internet, but somehow I could not get a gateway host on microservice. what should i do to ge the host of the gateway at microservices

**ı use ocelot for gateway**

Comment: who is generating this links?, in my opinion the link should not contain the complete path anyways but only relative path "{url}/api/customers/5/5?page=4&size=5" and {url} should be replace with your api gateway path while calling those APIs. this will also help in production when you really deploy your application.

Comment: so sorry i wrote wrong pagination response. endpoint is `https://localhost:5001/api/Customers?page=5&size=5` and pagging response is `_previous": "https://localhost:5001/api/Customers?page=4&size=5`  this line is generating link    `string paggingLink = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}{HttpContext.Request.Path}";`

Comment: in my opinion you should generate link `string paggingLink = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{url}/{HttpContext.Request.Path}";` like this. and replace {url} when calling any of the link. because even if you able to get gateway host in the service it will not help in production.

Comment: How the urls are generated?

Comment: ı do not understand what you mean @Chetan

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your service aware that it runs behind the reverse proxy.

```
// in ConfigureServices
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});

// in Configure
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

For more info: [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200502/yarp-rewriting-hardcoded-service-urls/72419043#72419043).

But I'm not sure Ocelot sets `X-Frowarded` headers when forwarding the requests. And since it was [abandoned by the maintainer](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/1539), the better option would be to replace Ocelot with [Yarp](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy). It does [add required headers to all requests](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/header-guidelines.html#x-forwarded--forwarded).